# sending file information with post request to google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to write a Google Appengine Post program that receive a file.

I observe that I get the content length of six bytes which is what the client
sent.  However, I cannot get the content.  When I try to read from the getInputStream
I get -1 the first time.  (I also tried reading into a ByteArray of six bytes, and
similarly, I get nothing in the buffer.)

```
package guestbook;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
public class XStore extends HttpServlet {
  public void doPost (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws
     IOException {
    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(XStore.class.getName());
     String ct;
     ct=req.getContentType();
     resp.setContentType("text/plain");
     String key = req.getParameter("key");
     String value = req.getParameter("value");
     DatastoreService d = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
     byte [] B;
     InputStream IS = req.getInputStream();
int i,le;
le = req.getContentLength(); 
StringBuffer rB = new StringBuffer();
int rv;
int c;
c = IS.read();
log.info("Srv = " + c );
```

This returns logs a -1
... rest of program omitted for brevity
My displays also indicated that le was six.

Here is the client

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
public class client {
public static void main (String a []  ) throws MalformedURLException,java.io.IOException,ProtocolException {
URL u = new URL("http://uthreee.appspot.com/XX?key=a&value=a");
HttpURLConnection H;
H = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
H.setRequestMethod("POST");
H.setDoOutput(true);
OutputStreamWriter w = new OutputStreamWriter(H.getOutputStream());
w.write("abc");
w.write("def");
w.close();
System.out.println(H.getResponseCode());
}}
```

Note that the response code is 200.
Thanks for any insight.  A student and myself spent over ten hours together
trying to find a way to transmit an XML file to the Google Appengine, but
cannot find a way to read the information sent by the client (which ultimately
will be an Android App).

Dr. Laurence Leff  Associate Professor of Computer Science,
Western Illinois University, Macomb IL 61455  on sabbatical

Comment: If you just want to upload a file, take a look at Google Cloud Storage and e.g. https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage to easily upload to it (from Android or any other Java app). Alternatively, take a look at [uploading to Blobstore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/), or if you really want full control, [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/). Avoid implementing file upload yourself, focus on the application you have in mind and leave the plumbing to a well-tested, proven library already written.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, using a browser form containing an <input type="file">, the [Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) definitely works with AppEngine.  In my case the form seemed to require the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute, and of course method="post".